# Can I have upkeep and random request running in same contract without a conflict in LINK balance?

Tags: chainlink

Would there be a conflict in LINK balance if I run Upkeep and VRFRandomness in the same contract?

As funding upkeep is through addFunds() function but as for VRFrandomness LINK token balance needs to be sent to the actual contract that deploys the random functions.

is it alright to send LINK tokens to the contract for VRFrandomness and to separately add LINK balance through addFunds() function/registry 'add fund' button for upkeep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this should be ok, as you said VRF uses LINK from the consuming contract itself, whereas with keepers, contracts are funded via the registry rather than within the consuming contract